# Proportional sampling and assign treatment group via Python for N times

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, sampling

In a hypothetical pandas Dataframe I have two types of fruits (ie. apple and orange. Column "fruitType"). Inside the apple category, I have 10 items and inside the orange category, I have 5 items. Please check out the screenshot below.

[Fruit dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BO6T.png)

I want to sample 40% of the total items from each **fruitType** (meaning 4 random apples and 2 random oranges). Next, I am going to randomly assign numbers in the range of (0-1) to each item included in the sample. If the number > median --> treatment, if the number < median --> control. Ultimately, I repeat the process for 350 times and would love to generate the table below.

[Ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxhZP.png)

I used the dataframe append method and it took forever to run the query when I tested on my original data (40k rows, 100+ fruitTypes). Is there any other way to write the for loop query below to speed up the processing speed?

Thanks so much!

My attempts:

**original dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'fruitName': ['fuji apple', 'gala apple', 'green apple', 'red apple', 'blue apple', 'black apple','pink apple','brown apple','old apple','ripe apple','mandarin orange', 'dark orange', 'ugly orange', 'beautiful orange','sour orange'],
        'fruitWeight': [0.1,0.5,0.2,3,3.5,2.1,5.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.5],
        'fruitType':['apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','orange','orange','orange','orange','orange']
       }
# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Print the output.
df
```

**stratified sampling + assign treatment / control groups**

```
# sample size = 40% of the population
pct_sampling_strat = 0.4

# repeat the process 350 times
repeat = 350

#create an empty dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame() 


for i in range(repeat):
    for k in ('apple','orange'):
        df['repeat_num'] = np.repeat(i,df.shape[0])
        mask = (df['repeat_num'] == i) & (df['fruitType'] == k)
        obs_sample = df[mask].sample(frac = pct_sampling_strat)
        shape = obs_sample.shape[0]
        obs_sample.loc[:,'rand'] = np.random.random(shape)
        med = obs_sample['rand'].median()
        obs_sample.loc[:,'isTreatment'] = obs_sample['rand'].apply(lambda rd: True if rd > med else False)
        df1 = df1.append([obs_sample])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

data = {'fruitName': ['fuji apple', 'gala apple', 'green apple', 'red apple', 'blue apple', 'black apple','pink apple','brown apple','old apple','ripe apple','mandarin orange', 'dark orange', 'ugly orange', 'beautiful orange','sour orange'],
        'fruitWeight': [0.1,0.5,0.2,3,3.5,2.1,5.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.5],
        'fruitType':['apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','orange','orange','orange','orange','orange']
       }
# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# sample size = 40% of the population
pct_sampling_strat = 0.4

# repeat the process 350 times
repeat = 350

def sample_df(i,k,df):
    obs_sample = df[df['fruitType'] == k].sample(frac = pct_sampling_strat)
    obs_sample['repeat_num'] = i
    obs_sample['rand'] = np.random.random()
    med = obs_sample['rand'].median()
    obs_sample['isTreatment'] = obs_sample['rand'].apply(lambda rd: rd > med)
    return obs_sample

start_time = time.time()
df_list = []
for i in range(repeat):
    for k in ('apple','orange'):
        obs_sample = sample_df(i,k,df)
        df_list.append(obs_sample)

df1 = pd.concat(df_list)

end_time = time.time()
print('run time: ',end_time-start_time)

out:
run time:  1.1831037998199463
```

You can also put `sample_df(i,k,df)` into the thread

Comment: OMG you are a genius! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so so much!